# iOS: add constraints between a xib view and its superview

Tags: ios, view, autolayout, constraints, xib

I'm adding a view from a xib file to a table view controller and then placing this out of view so that when the user taps a button the view scrolls down from under the navigation bar to be visible. Here's the view that drops down:

[image]

This works fine on iPhone 6 but anything smaller and the drop down view loses its constraints and looks all jumbled up like below:

[image]

I believe this is the case because there are no constraints being set between the drop down view and the table view (the superview). I was using [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) however since iOS8.3/Xcode 6.3 this doesn't seem to do anything anymore.

What options do i have for adding a constraint to drop down view so it is aligned with the top, left and right edges of the superview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I ended up just setting the frame of the xib view manually upon creation for the different screen sizes