# How to add constraint to custom table view cell xib file?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xib, nslayoutconstraint

To implement expanding custom table view cell, I used custom xib file with UITableViewCell.

But I cannot find constraint panel in that xib file.

In order to fit to variable device size, I have to set trailing constrain.
Is it impossible to set constraint in custom xib file?

Comment: yes its possible to add constraints, just like you in xib file.

Comment: if you refer to the 'main' view:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527478/adding-constraint-to-the-main-view-in-a-xib and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711012/ios-add-constraints-between-a-xib-view-and-its-superview

Comment: @user3802077 Thank you for your response. But I cannot see constraint panel in the xib interface. Do I have to place UITableViewController? Now I placed UITableViewCell

Comment: @Aamir Is it possible in case of placing UITableViewCell only(there isn't any controller)? I cannot find constraint control buttons.

Comment: posted answer for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select your .xib file -> Show File Inspector -> Use Auto Layout

Constraints will start appearing at bottom.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. You saved my time. Really helpful.

Comment: sorry I cannot up vote now. You know my reputation is under 15. When I can do it, I'll up vote it.

Comment: You saved my day, didn't expect that can be the solution.

Comment: "Use Auto Layout" doesn't exist in Xcode 11.3.1.